# Alocação de memoria - Loop infinito ao usar a função free()

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um codigo em C para testar conceitos de Estrutura de dados que são passados na minha universidade. Porém me deparei com um erro ao usar a função `free`, que gera um loop infinito no meu codigo. Caso eu a remova o codigo funciona. utilizei o `free` na função `InserePrimeiro` (Senhores, eu não sou o responsável pelos nomes das funções). Se alguém puder me guiar a solução eu agradeceria.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Nodo {
    int valor;
    struct Nodo *proximo;
} Nodo;

typedef struct Lista {
    Nodo *primeiro;
    Nodo *ultimo;
} Lista;

void FLVazia(Lista *l) {
    l->primeiro = NULL;
    l->ultimo = NULL;
}

int Vazia(Lista l) {
    if (l.primeiro == NULL)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void InserePrimeiro(int x, Lista *l) {
    Nodo *novo = (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    novo->valor = x;
    novo->proximo = NULL;
    l->primeiro = novo;
    l->ultimo = novo;
    free(novo);
}

void Insere(int x, Lista *l) {
    Nodo *novo = (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    novo->valor = x;
    novo->proximo = NULL;
    l->ultimo->proximo = novo;
    l->ultimo = novo;
}

void Imprime(Lista *l) {
    Nodo *aux = (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    aux = l->primeiro;
    while(aux != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", aux->valor);
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }
}

int Acessa(int p, Lista *l) {
    Nodo *aux = (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    aux = l->primeiro;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<p; i++) {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }
    return aux->valor;
}

int Retira(int p, Lista *l) {
    Nodo *aux = (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    aux = l->primeiro;
    int removido;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<p-1; i++) {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }
    removido = aux->proximo->valor;
    aux->proximo = aux->proximo->proximo;
    return removido;
}

void main() {
    Lista li;
    FLVazia(&li);
    int valor;
    int option=100;
    while(option != 0 ) {
        printf("Escolha uma opcao:\n");
        printf("1 - Verifica se a lista esta vazia\n");
        printf("2 - Inserir na primeira posicao\n");
        printf("3 - Insere um item na ultima posição\n");
        printf("4 - Acessa uma posicao\n");
        printf("5 - Retira um item da lista\n");
        printf("6 - Imprime a lista\n");
        printf("0 - Sair\n");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option) {
        case 0:
            printf("Saindo...");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Lista vazia?:%d\n",Vazia(li));
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Valor:");
            scanf("%d",&valor);
            InserePrimeiro(valor,&li);
            Imprime(&li);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Valor:");
            scanf("%d",&valor);
            Insere(valor,&li);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("posicao:");
            scanf("%d",&valor);
            printf("%d\n",Acessa(valor,&li));
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("posicao:");
            scanf("%d",&valor);
            printf("removido: %d\n",Retira(valor,&li));
            break;
        case 6:
            Imprime(&li);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você acabou de efetuar o `malloc` do elemento `novo`, logo não faz sentido efetuar o a liberação (free) dele logo abaixo. Se você o fizer, a memória estará desalocada logo que o método retornar. Ao tentar imprimir o valor depois de inserir, o código tentará acessar uma região não alocada (o primeiro elemento, que tinha tido memória alocada para ele, foi liberado logo depois), o que resulta em **comportamento não definido**, o que significa basicamente que qualquer coisa pode acontecer, daí seu programa congela.

Então a resposta já está na sua pergunta: apenas retire o free do método `InserePrimeiro` e seu código estará ok.

Comment: na `Retira()`, que é onde o `free()` deveria acontecer, ele está alocando mais um elemento, por razões que não consigo discernir.

Comment: Pois é, essa memória está vazando, nem tinha reparado... pelo jeito o camarada está começando a aprender. Abordei na resposta apenas a petição inicial :)

Comment: é senhores, não sou familiarizado com C e com esses conceitos. Sou estudante de ciência da computação e essa matéria é estrutura de dados I. Vou me esforçar para entender tudo direitinho. Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. :D